# Chrome open with "data;;" adress with selenium in python

Tags: selenium

I am a newbie to Selenium and trying to get some image from the website.
When it runs, it prints `Done` well and also pop-up chrome.
However, it keeps open chrome with `data;;`

```
from selenium import webdriver
import urllib.request
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=" chromedriver location it is ")
driver.get = ("https://store.musinsa.com/app/contents/bestranking?new_product_yn=Y")
print('Done')
```

Screenshot:
[image]

information

- chrome version : 76.0.3809.132(64bit)
- chromDriver version: ChromeDriver 76.0.3809.126

Comment: That is the default screen when selenium starts up. You need to call driver.get(url) to navigate to your target site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the get method [Getting Started](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html)

```
driver.get("https://store.musinsa.com/app/contents/bestranking?new_product_yn=Y")
```